# Sorting Array using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array as shown below:

```
var fruits = ['0-2','1-1','12-2','14-2','2-3','21-1','4-1'];
```

It gives me output like this:

`0-2,1-1,12-2,14-2,2-3,21-1,4-1`.

I want to sort this array and get output as:

`0-2,1-1,2-3,4-1,12-2,14-2,21-1` using JavaScript/jQuery.

I tired using `fruits.sort();` but that does not work, any suggestions?

Comment: Great. What have you tried so far? Post your code if you want debugging help.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.sort`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with passing function for compare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to format the input (by removing the hyphen) before comparison to get the expected result:

```js
var fruits = ['0-2','1-1','12-2','14-2','2-3','21-1','4-1'];

fruits.sort(function(a, b){
  a = a.replace('-', '')
  b = b.replace('-', '');
  return a - b;
});
console.log(fruits)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass a compareFunction and `split()` the string and compare the first element of the array

```js
var fruits = ['0-2', '1-1', '12-2', '14-2', '2-3', '21-1', '4-1'];

fruits.sort((a, b) => a.split('-')[0] - b.split('-')[0]);

console.log(fruits);
```

Doc: [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)